# Connection of two tables

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a problem with making a query to `MYSQL` which will combine two tables.

Mainly I want to through such a query

```html
<?php 
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
$wynik = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") 
or die('Błąd zapytania'); 

/* 
wyświetlamy wyniki, sprawdzamy, 
czy zapytanie zwróciło wartość większą od 0 
*/ 
if(mysql_num_rows($wynik) > 0) { 
    /* jeżeli wynik jest pozytywny, to wyświetlamy dane */ 
    echo "<table cellpadding=\"2\" border=1>"; 
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik)) { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td><a href='pokaz.php?id=".$r['userId']."'>".$r['userName']."</a></td>"; 
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</table>"; 
} 

?>
```

and after clicking on the link, the pictures that this user added showed me

the file **pokaz.php** looks like this

my tables

[image]

[image]

Please, let someone ask me this question, I will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$wynik = mysqli_query($con, "select `user`.userId, `user`.userName, `pictures`.image_name from `user` inner join `user_uploads` on `user_uploads`.user_id_fk = `user`.id");

/*
wyświetlamy wyniki, sprawdzamy,
czy zapytanie zwróciło wartość większą od 0
*/


if($wynik) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($wynik) > 0) {
        ;
        /* jeżeli wynik jest pozytywny, to wyświetlamy dane */
        echo "<table cellpadding=\"2\" border=1>";
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wynik)) {
            $imgName = $r['image_name'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='pokaz.php?id=" . $r['userId'] . "'>" . $r['userName'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<img src='/uploads/$imgName' />";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}

?>
```

**UPDATE:** 
if you want to show images in **pokaz.php** for each user:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$wynik = mysqli_query($con, "select `user`.userId, `user`.userName, `pictures`.image_name from `user` inner join `user_uploads` on `user_uploads`.user_id_fk = `user`.id");

/*
wyświetlamy wyniki, sprawdzamy,
czy zapytanie zwróciło wartość większą od 0
*/


if($wynik) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($wynik) > 0) {
        ;
        /* jeżeli wynik jest pozytywny, to wyświetlamy dane */
        echo "<table cellpadding=\"2\" border=1>";
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wynik)) {
            $imgName = $r['image_name'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='pokaz.php?id=" . $r['userId'] . "'>" . $r['userName'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<img src='/uploads/$imgName' />";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}

?>
```

**pokaz.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['userId'])){
    $userId = $_GET['userId'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    $query = "select image_name from user_uploads";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);


    if($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $imgName =  $row['image_name'];
            echo "<img src='/uploads/$imgName' /></br>";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Błąd zapytania" = Error question

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /pokaz.php on line 10 .....what is this $yourBaseUrl. ?

Comment: last update. look at my updated answer. first of all check $wynik (result). If this check returns false then you have problem in connection

Comment: what is this $yourBaseUr ???

and

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /pokaz.php on line 20

Comment: path where is located your images. For example '/img/' or something different

Comment: hmmm proszę spojrzeć na artwebs.pl/wszystkie.php

you can not see the result

Comment: so how you want this table look alike?

Comment: so what should I do ? how to do it ?

Comment: you have image name in $imgName varriable and treat it as you want?

Comment: yes, I want to display it so that, for example, I click on the user's name and only its pictures are shown, for example on another page

Comment: where is located this uploaded images?

Comment: the link to the image is in mysql
and the image itself on the server

Comment: I updated again my answer. Deleted $baseUrl varriable. And in my example photos will be shown alongside with usernames in your grid.

Comment: I assumed that pictures located in a root directory of your website

Comment: Thank you though I still have a problem :( You would not like to rewrite it somehow? So that on one page there are links with usernames and after clicking you switched to a new page and displayed its photos.

Comment: I saw your page and you have problem in apostrophe. Write like that: '/uploads/$imgName'

Comment: Let's start from the beginning :
I have a website everyone.php where all users from the USERS table are displayed
Now let's say I have a link <a href='view.php?id=".$r['userId']."'> ". $ r ['userName']." </a>

After clicking the link, it passes to the VIEW.PHP website where the images of this user are shown (images are stored on the server) the link to them is in MYSQL.

The pictures are assigned to the user by his name

Comment: I think you should write new question. It is another topic

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not create a new question.

Comment: why you can't??

Comment: You have reached your question limit :)

Comment: if my answer helped you, accept it and you could ask a new question

Comment: $wynik = mysqli_query($con, "select `users`.*, `user_uploads`.* from `users` inner join `user_uploads` where user_id_fk='".$_GET['id']."'") or die('Błąd zapytania'); 

I gave this query and it works, but the result shows me as many as 5 pieces

Comment: Let's say 1 user 1 picture
but when in mysql I will give 1 user added 2 pictures, the result I have 5x 2 uploaded images

Comment: It turns out that how many users in the USER table repeats the picture so many times

Comment: soo you want to show just one picture to the single user?

Comment: I want to show all photos of one user
For example, the user has 10 pictures that shows me his 10 photos

Comment: maybe I understand what you want, look again my updated answer